# What launcher/cannon does the most DPS?

Tags: halo-4

What launcher/cannon does the most DPS (damage per second) in Halo 4?

**(assuming the player has a relatively accurate shot; maybe an 8 on a scale of 1-10)**

- The Rocket Launcher?
- Spartan Laser?
- Sticky Detonator?
- Concussion Rifle?
- Incineration Cannon?
- Rail Gun
- Other?

Comment: Define "effective".

Comment: What launcher/cannon does the most damage with the largest spread?

Comment: @DesignerGuy That's a completely different question to the one asked.

Comment: @JamesJiao - That doesn't mean it wasn't the information I was intending to obtain.

Comment: Couldn't you just tag them all in one comment? Edit: I see now, thanks.

Comment: Nope. **"Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified"** I wish you could. I think it is a spam-prevention thing. I think it would make more sense to have a 3-person mention limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the launcher/cannon that does the most damage with the largest spread would be the incineration cannon. there is the initial blast on contact that has the payload of the run-of-the-mill rocket launcher and then explodes in 6 separate explosions around the initial hit that each do about as much damage as the plasma grenade.